# Does "min_free_kbytes=256000" allow caching even when the free mem is at 250 MB?

Tags: kernel, memory-usage, virtualization, cache

I am actually plotting a memory graph which shows the free, cached, used and buffer memory on my VM, And i am taking these values using the `sar -r` command. My `min_free_kbytes` is 256000.

[image]

Now, The cached memory is continuously increasing until there is only 500MB of free memory. Why is the cached memory reduced as soon as the free memory comes down to around 500 MB even though the `min_free_kbytes` is set to 250 MB?

Comment: Are cached and free the only classes of memory in your VM?

Comment: No, There are "Used" and "Buffers" too. I excluded them here as they are almost stable.

Comment: You might find that if you add Used, Buffers, and Cached you are hitting your target mark when the cached memory is reduced. It's hard to say as your image only shows cached memory and an inference as to free memory. Where and how did you obtain this graph?

Answer (score 2):

The tunable variable at `/proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes` does not define the exact point when the system will begin reclaiming various forms of cached memory, if any is available.

The tunable variable at `/proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes` is used to calculate at least a **minimum** number of memory pages and a **low** number of memory pages, per zone if applicable. Once the number of available pages of memory crosses below the **low** threshold the memory management system will begin to attempt to reclaim available cached memory pages. The objective is to never actually hit the **minimum** number of memory pages (although it can), while maintaining room (and response times) for low latency memory requirements.

See also:
`/proc/meminfo`
`/proc/zoneinfo`

Linux memory management is a big big subject, and my answer is superficial.